# Ubuntu Configuring Printers

Tags: printing

I having issues connecting to my Brother printer (DCP 7030) using Ubuntu 11.10. There are no drivers available for the same in Ubuntu, as its one of the latest printers available in market. Unfortunately the installation CD's coming with the printer are for Windows and Mac. Like to know, where can i get the drivers for the same.

Any assistance, is highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Do I need to repost my questions again?

Comment: Edit your question removing one of your questions and repost it as a NEW question.

Comment: Removed one of the question as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

[Brothers Linux Drivers](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#DCP-7030)

[image]